# PHP - Determine if data already deleted

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, sql-delete

Well, for deleting a data from db query will be like this:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM MyGuests WHERE id=3";
```

I want when users stuck on browser cache or clicked twice on delete icon or.. they get an error like "this data already delete".

already when i delete a data (ex. id 3) and when want to delete same id again (id 3) want to get an error. i think i need something like ON DUPLICATE key.

Comment: My only thought is, who cares if a row was already deleted? I mean it doesn't hurt anything if you run the delete query and nothing was deleted. Also, you will likely get false errors if there are two users viewing the same page and one deletes a row and the second tries to deleted the same row. It isn't really all that useful to know you tried to delete something that no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of rows affected by the delete with [mysqli_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php). If the number of rows is zero then you display the error.

Comment: I think you mean [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php). *num_rows is for the number of rows in a select result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the affected_rows count to determine if there was any data deleted, when zero rows affected then show your message.